# Kotlin Runnable vs () -> Unit

Tags: kotlin, jvm

What is major difference between those two?

For example when creating custom class, which handles what thread should do I am left with 2 options:

```
class ThreadHandler : Runnable {
    private val thread = Thread(this)

    override fun run() {}
}
```

AND

```
class ThreadHandler : () -> Unit {
    private val thread = Thread(this)

    override fun invoke() {}
}
```

I am asking for:

1. Advantages and disadvantages of each other (because I believe that Runnable is implemented and "() -> Unit" is extended)
2. Which is preferred way of using in this scenario

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The differences are mainly about language support, interoperability, history, and usage.

`() -> Unit` is a Kotlin type, representing a function that takes no parameters and returning nothing useful.  These function types are fundamental to Kotlin, and are used throughout the standard library, so you can pass it to umpteen extension functions.  The language syntax also supports them; for example, you can simply append `()` to run it.

`Runnable` is a Java interface, defining a single method that takes no parameters and returns nothing useful.  Java doesn't have first-class functions; instead, it gets some of the benefits using interfaces.  (From Java 8, those were formalised as ‘functional interfaces’ and could be implemented by lambdas where the context provided enough info; but `Runnable` itself dates right back to Java 1.0.)  There's less language support for them, so you'd have to append `.run()` to run it.  Also, although they're general-purpose, Runnables are often used to provide code for a thread to execute, so are associated with that execution model.

So while the two constructs mean roughly the same thing, the former looks more natural and interoperates much better with lots of Kotlin code, while the latter interoperates better with older Java code and tends to be used for threads.

And to answer your specific points:

1. Yes, being a type, I think `() -> Unit` is technically extended rather than implemented, but the difference isn't significant here.
2. Unless you have a particular need to interoperate mainly with older Java code, I'd recommend using the Kotlin function type.

Comment: Everything I wanted to know explained to detail. Thank you so much.

Comment: My pleasure! That's what this site should be for. (By the way, I think it's usually recommended to wait at least a day before accepting an answer. After all, someone in another time-zone might come up with an answer even better than mine, however impossible that might sound :-)

Comment: I know, not my first question. But in this scenario there is no other way to do it. I know that I shouldn't extend Thread class, because I am not adding any extra functionality to it, so it can be only Runnable or Kotlin function.